# To show full text without truncating with more less feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We are working on Angular js application, in our application we have to implement read more and less functionality with text showing in table or div. To achieve this we have used READMORE.js, this working fine with normal text.

But we have to show some text in red color, so we have added span in the text :

```
<span class="my-red-text">any text any text.....</span>
```

Whenever above text is loaded with more option of readmore, then it truncate the text as :

```
y-red-text">any text any text.....
```

It do not show the text in red color, also cut the text, the text saved in database is correct, but loading text is truncating. Also this is not necessary span is present at start of the text, it can be anywhere within the text.

[Truncating text in Application with readmore.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v73mA.jpg)

How can I show all text without truncating ?

Comment: Can you please upload the code snippet of what you have worked?
At least the java script code and html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue while working with readmore.js.

I have done following changes in **readmore.min.js** :

In methods : m() and l(). I have checked for html tags as follows and changed the limit of text :

```
if(r.lessText!=undefined && (r.lessText.indexOf('>') > -1 || r.lessText.indexOf('<') > -1)){
   var indexOfStartTag= r.lessText.indexOf('<');
   r.lessText = r.lessText.substring(0, indexOfStartTag);
   r.hmLimit = indexOfStartTag;
}else{
   r.hmLimit = r.hmLimit && r.hmLimit <= 0 ? void 0 : r.hmLimit
}
```

This worked fine for me. Hope this helps you!!